# How to save stat of all files found in a search?

Tags: find, stat

I had a cron which removes all files with a specific pattern from temp.

```
find /tmp/* -type f -iname magick-* -exec rm {} \;
```

Now, I want to log the stat of all files before deleting them for future analysis.

I tried doing the following, but it doesn't work if search output is more than one.

```
find /tmp/* -type f -iname magick-* -exec stat {} \;
```

How to make this work for multiple results, also how to log it to a file?

Comment: Using quotes in your iname query should work: `find /tmp/* -type f -iname "magick-*" -exec stat {} \;`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show what *does* happen when you try it. Just saying "it doesn't work" is NEVER correct.

I suspect that your problems mey be related to one or more of the following:

- Quote the pattern or escape the `*`. If you don't, and you have one or more files in your current directory that matches that pattern, the pattern will be expanded to the list of matching files and substituted into your command, which is *not* what you want.
- Don't use `/tmp/*` for find, simply use `/tmp`, `find` is perfectly capable of recursing into the given directory by itself; it will then also find any files whose name starts with a dot.

Other than that, if the `rm` would work, then the `stat` should also work.

Note also that you could combine the two:

```
find /tmp -type f -iname 'magick-*' -exec stat {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

First the `stat` will be performed, then, if the `stat` didn't fail, `rm` is executed.

You can save the output by simply redirecting `find`'s output to whatever file you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use everything in one go. Also use `+` instead which will be faster as it executes the whole action at once.

```
find /tmp -type f -iname 'magick-*'-exec stat {} + -exec sh -c 'rm -rf  $@' _ {} + | tee -a log_to_file
```